# How to divide a main component into two sub components

Tags: angular, typescript

I am developing an Angular application, i have to switch between two buttons(btn1, btn2) in a toolbar. These buttons are in a component called "design". it is part of the App component. The toolbar also has 5 more buttons with different functionalities. I want to implement these five functionalities commonly for both buttons(btn1, btn2) with different logic. If i do everything in the same component the code becomes more complex and lengthy. can someone please suggest me, what is the best way to do it with less complexity.

[Edit]
File structure

```
Appcomonent.ts
Appcompontent.html
Appcomponent.css
Appmodule.ts
DesignComponent.ts
Designcomponent.html
Designcomponent1
Designcomponent2
```

In Designcomponent.html i have code for buttons
In Designcomponent.ts i have code for buttons logic.
I want to bind Designcomponent1.ts to btn1 in Designcomponent.ts and DesignComponent.ts to btn2 in Designcomponent.ts and other five buttons also. How can i add routing to them.

Comment: Breaking components into smaller and sensible components is always considered better. You have not shared any code so cannot give the exact technicalities. Try to always break the bigger problem into smaller ones.

Comment: @adibro500 Thanks for your Reply. How can i add routing and share global variables for sub components from main component. I have edited my question. Can you please have a look at it.

Comment: You have to create a routing module and add routes that point to the corresponding components. Then you have to import these modules inside the main module. Please refer the official angular docs: https://angular.io/start/routing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your folder structure and file structure should be like following.

```
parentcomponent/
├── childcomponent1/
│   ├── childcomponent1.component.html
│   ├── childcomponent1.component.ts
│   ├── childcomponent1.component.scss
├── childcomponent2/
│   ├── childcomponent2.component.html
│   ├── childcomponent2.component.ts
│   ├── childcomponent2.component.scss
└── parentcomponent.component.html
└── parentcomponent.component.ts
└── parentcomponent.component.scss
└── parentcomponent.module.ts
└── parentcomponent.service.ts
```

And then import childcomponent1.component & childcomponent1.component class in Parent Component.